# Convert array results in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

How can I convert the following

```
 @results = [{"id"=>"one", "url"=>"/new/file_one.jpg"}, 
             {"id"=>"two", "url"=>"/new/file_two.jpg"}]
```

to

```
 @results = {"one" => "/new/file_one.jpg", 
             "two" => "/new/file_two.jpg"}
```

Should I use "map" or "collect"? Starting with..

```
@results.map{ |x| x['id']}
```

Comment: Your desired `@results` isn't Ruby at all, what should it really look like? `@results = { 'one' => ... }` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
@results = [{"id"=>"one", "url"=>"/new/file_one.jpg"},
             {"id"=>"two", "url"=>"/new/file_two.jpg"}]
Hash[@results.map { |x| [x['id'], x['url']] }]
# => {"one"=>"/new/file_one.jpg", "two"=>"/new/file_two.jpg"}
```

In Ruby 2.1+, you can also use [`Enumerable#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h):

```
@results.map { |x| [x['id'], x['url']] }.to_h
# => {"one"=>"/new/file_one.jpg", "two"=>"/new/file_two.jpg"}
```

Comment: @igor, BTW, you expect a hash object as a result : `{"one"=>"/new/file_one.jpg", "two"=>"/new/file_two.jpg"}`, not `["one" => "/new/file_one.jpg", "two" => "/new/file_two.jpg"]`. Right?

Comment: Whether the OP expected an array with `=>` or `{... => ...}` isn't too important as Ruby will convert the second to the first anyway: `['a' => 1] # => [{"a"=>1}]`

Comment: @theTinMan, Nice to learn it. Thank you. But they are different: A hash and an array of a hash.

Comment: @falsetru yes, that's what I was looking for, will edit the question, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the array and extract the values of each sub-hash:

```
[
  {"id"=>"one", "url"=>"/new/file_one.jpg"},
  {"id"=>"two", "url"=>"/new/file_two.jpg"}
].map(&:values).to_h 
# => {"one"=>"/new/file_one.jpg", "two"=>"/new/file_two.jpg"}
```

If your Ruby doesn't support `to_h` then wrap it all in `Hash[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
results.map{ |x| {x['id'] => x['url']} }
```